# Javascript: can't add href to list item

Tags: javascript, html-lists, href

I am trying to add a new item to a list item. But the below code isn't adding Hyperlink to the list item  I want. Can someone please advise what's wrong?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul id="list1">
      <li>Ut enim ad minim veniam.</li>
      <li>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
//create new li element
var newListItem = document.createElement("li");
newListItem.textContent = "...ooo";
var ulist = document.getElementById("list1");
console.log("adding link..");
newListItem.setAttribute('href', "http://www.msn.com");
ulist.appendChild(newListItem);
console.log("added item");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`li` doesn't have the `href` attribute, you have to wrap an `a` tag inside `li`.

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
var ulist = document.getElementById("list1");
var newItem = document.createElement("li");

a.textContent = "...ooo";
a.setAttribute('href', "http://www.msn.com");
newItem.appendChild(a);
ulist.appendChild(newItem);
```

***[The DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/BFvXf/)***

Answer (score 2):

Though solved, I add some more information for you to read :)

### Content and attributes

Each element has a [content model](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/dom.html#content-models):

> *``[…] a description of the element's expected contents. An HTML element must have contents that match the requirements described in the element's content model.[…]''*

As such the `<ul>` element has a content model. Looking at [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) we find it to be:

- Zero or more [li](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) and [script-supporting](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#script-supporting-elements-0) elements.

By this we can conclude that we can not have an anchor, `a`, inside the `ul` element. But what about adding a `href` attribute to the `ul`?

Then we look at the [Content attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-attributes).

> A normative list of attributes that may be specified on the element
>   (except where otherwise disallowed), along with non-normative
>   descriptions of those attributes. (The content to the left of the dash
>   is normative, the content to the right of the dash is not.)

For `ul` we find:

- [Global attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes)

The Global attributes are the following:

- accesskey
- class
- contenteditable
- dir
- draggable
- dropzone
- hidden
- id
- lang
- spellcheck
- style
- tabindex
- title
- translate

In addition it can have various *event handler attributes*, like `onmouseover`, `onclick`, `on...` and [ARIA attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA). But, as we see, no `href` attribute.

In conclusion we now know that:

1. `ul` can not have an anchor as a child.
2. `ul` can not have the `href` attribute.

---

### But, the question was about `href` on `li` element!

As `li` and `ul` / `ol` are intertwined we first had a look at `ul`. For `li` we follow the same procedure: The [*content model* for `li`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) is:

- [Flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1)

Now, that opens up a wide range of possibilities. Here we find `a` at top of the list.

And what about the *attributes*? For `li` we find:

- Global attributes
    If the element is a child of an ol element: value - Ordinal value of the list item

In other words, we now know:

1. `ul` *can **not** have* an anchor as a child.
2. `ul` *can **not** have* the `href` attribute.
3. `li` *can have* an anchor as a child.
4. `li` *can **not** have* the `href` attribute.

---

### Solution

As pointed out by others, is to add it to an anchor that we put as a child of a `li` element:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="myurl">Hello</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `href` attribute is not meaningful on an `<li>` element. If you want to make an list element into a link, you will need to wrap its contents in an `<a>` element and apply the `href` to that.

Comment: One should not wrap the `li` inside an anchor but the other way around.

Comment: Right! I meant wrapping the contents of the list element, not the whole thing.

Comment: Thought as much, but it was not clear to that point. Good fix ;)

Answer (score 0):

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/wazeleda/1/edit)

```
var ulist = document.getElementById("list1");
var newListItem = document.createElement("li");
var newAnchor = document.createElement("a");
newAnchor.textContent = "...ooo";
newAnchor.setAttribute('href', "http://www.msn.com");
newListItem.appendChild(newAnchor);
ulist.appendChild(newListItem);
```

yep so basically you missed the `anchor` tag creation.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to simply use the link() method. For example:

```
//create new li element
let newListItem = document.createElement("li");
let ulist = document.getElementById("list1");
newListItem.innerHTML = "...ooo".link("http://www.msn.com");
ulist.appendChild(newListItem);
```