# Hyperlink an li using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, navigation

I currently have the following navigation bar:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab-1">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">MyRole</a></li>
    <!--<li><a href="#tab-3">Services</a></li>-->
    <li><a href="#tab-4">CSR</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-5">Vendors</a></li>
</ul>
```

For the Vendors tab I would like to use Javascript to hyperlink it.
I have tried the following Javascript code but did not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething() {
        $.get("hyperlink-here");
        return false;
    }
</script>
<li><a href="#tab-5" onclick="doSomething();">Vendors</a></li>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `window.location='..'`? What functionality do you exactly need?

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: `$.get` won't do anything by itself without a complete callback to process response

Comment: This needs further explanation. I don't believe you need to use javascript. Just create divs with the respective ID of the link, right?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question:

```js
$(".tabs li a").on("click", function()
{
  console.log($(this).data("link"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
<li><a data-link="#tab-1">News</a></li>
<li><a data-link="#tab-2">MyRole</a></li>
<!--<li><a href="#tab-3">Services</a></li>-->
<li><a data-link="#tab-4">CSR</a></li>
<li><a data-link="#tab-5">Vendors</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your li tag (for which you want to add a hyperlink) with anchor tag like        
    `<a href=""> <li></li> </a>.`
Or if you want to do it with javascript: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977349/javascript-cant-add-href-to-list-item)